# Observable objects / dynamic interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics, configuration

I'm currently looking for a nice and clean way to manage/store application configuration. I've seen many approaches and frameworks, yet I'm not really satisfied because most I've seen follow a simple idea:

```
* Store 'some' data
* Retrieve 'some' data
```

Which might look like this (pseudo) for a simple key value store:

```
public T Get<T>(string key);
public void Save<T>(string key, T value);
```

The .NET configuration framework living inside `System.Configuration` that has been around for a while tackles this nicely because it allows strongly typed configuration objects by providing a set of base classes which one can derives from to describe the configuration scheme. However this requires a lot of work and boilerplate code to get things running.

What I got in mind is something like this:

```
public IConfiguration<TSet> : TSet {

    void Commit();
    void Refresh();

}

public class MyConfigurationSet {
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
}

// usage
var config = new JsonConfiguration<MyConfigurationSet>(MYPATH);
config.Value1 = "Hello";
config.Commit();
```

Is there any way to make such a thing possible? In order to do this, I would need to a) derive from a generic type and b) "observe" an instance of that generic type for changes in order to track changes etc., and I'm not aware of a way those things are possible (*for now, e.g. for the first part, I can't see any reason why it isn't possible other than it's currently not*). Anyone got an idea?

Comment: did you have a look at saving user/application settings ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deriving from a generic type is no problem:

```
public class JsonConfiguration<T> : IConfiguration<T>
{
}
```

Is perfectly permissible.

As far as observing it goes, I would put a generic type constraint on the type implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that you can register for the `PropertyChanged` event. You can't just "trap" a random variable assignment, the client code has to notify you.

```
public class JsonConfiguration<T> : IConfiguration<T> where T:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
}
```